# How can I allow only specific users to view specific fields of a content type in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, entityreference

I'm setting up a Drupal 7 site where members with the role of "student" are asked to submit reviews about members with the role of "teacher." I need each student to be able to review all the teachers at once, and then I need to build a view where each teacher can only see reviews related to them. The reviews are part of a larger application form, so some fields in the content type need to be viewable to all teachers.

I know how to set up an entity reference view so that students can select teachers from a drop-down. My question is- **can I associate a text field with a particular entity?** If I could do this, I could configure the teachers' view to only show student feedback fields that were "tagged" with the current user.

To clarify: I can't make a content type that would be filled out multiple times by a student - once for each teacher - because the students need to only create **one post**. The content type should look something like this:

**Pick your first choice teacher:** *(this is where I've been using an entity reference drop-down)*
**Explain your first choice:** *(this should be a text field that only the student, admin, and teacher selected in the first drop-down field have permission to see)*

**Pick your second choice teacher:** *(this is another entity reference drop-down)*
**Explain your second choice:** *(another text field, visible only the student, admin, and teacher selected in the second drop-down field)*

Can I possibly acomplish this with the Rules module?

Answer (score 4):

Try [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions); it's built just for that.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Answer (score 1):

Create a content type "teacher assessment" where each assessment will be related to a teacher. The author of the "teacher assessment" content type would be the student who created this assessment.

You can use the [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module, which has integration support for the Views module.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I am using the Entity Reference module, but I can't make a content type that would be filled out multiple times by a student - once for each teacher - because the students need to only create one post each. I put a description of basically what the content type should look like in the question above.